# выбор option появляется input

Tags: javascript

Ребят помогите пожалуйста, не могу написать скрипт javi,  мне надо чтобы при выборе в селекте "продажа" появлялся блок "инпут", ну и чтобы пропадал когда другие выбираешь

Выберите
        Продажа
        Обмен
        Даром

в css блок div id="price" display: none;

Comment: Есть подозрение, что в таких случаях приводят достаточный для понимания ситуации код, а не просто вываливают на пользователей кучу информации :)

Comment: я писал сам это в 4 строках javi у меня появлялся блок но он не видим почему то:(

Comment: На первый селект вешается слушатель события `onchange`, который вызывается при выборе. Внутри функции проверяем текущее значение (`value`) нашего селекта: если выбран нужный нам пункт - показываем второй инпут. И да, @SleepyPanda права, в таких вопросах полагается прикладывать имеющийся код. html + js. желательно - в виде сниппета, который можно тут же запустить.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

На первый селект вешается слушатель события `onchange`, который вызывается при выборе. Внутри функции проверяем, что сейчас выбрано: если нужный нам пункт - показываем второй инпут.

С использованием jQuery это выглядит так:

рабочий пример на jsfiddle (местные сниппеты барахлят): https://jsfiddle.net/ipshenicyn/0m8xbsy1/2/

HTML

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="select" id="select">
    <option value="1">Первый пункт</option>
    <option value="2">Второй пункт</option>
    <option value="3">Третий пункт</option>
    <option value="4">Четвертый пункт</option>
</select>
<input id="input" type="text" name="input" style="display:none">
```

JS

```
$("#select").on('change', function(){
    if($(this).val() == 3){
        $("#input").show();
    } else {
        $("#input").hide();
    }
})
```

Comment: Иван спасибо большое, я понял свою ошибку, я в value указывал не цифры а текст, как поменял на цифры все сработало, прошу прощения что заставил вас все написать, я внимательно не прочитал как тут отправлять скрипты(

Comment: @Евгений ничего страшного, главное что разобрались. Вообще говоря, нет никакой разницы, цифры  в value или текст. Ошибка у вас была, видимо, в чем-то другом. Отметьте, пожалуйста, ответ полезным, если он вам помог. Для этого поставьте галочку слева от ответа.

Comment: иван не могли бы вы мне помочь в валидации?http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/557704/